# How to create a lambda permission for a custom websocket request authorizer with CloudFormation for API Gateway?

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I've been trying to create a lambda permission for a websockets request authorizer for API Gateway and the $connect route. The AWS documenation mentions nothing about creating the proper lambda permission for a websocket authorizer. I keep getting a 500 error when I try to connect to my custom authorizer.

Since the AWS documenation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-lambda-auth.html) does not mention anything about this permission, I assume one would have to create a lambda permission just like a TOKEN authorizer.

The custom authorizer was created with my CloudFormation script as follows:

```
# ***************************************************************
# API Gateway Websocket Authorizer
# ***************************************************************
WebsocketAuthorizer:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer'
    DependsOn: Lambda
    Properties:
        Name: WebsocketAuthorizer
        ApiId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub ${Env}-${AWS::Region}-altosignal-global-websockets
        AuthorizerType: REQUEST
        AuthorizerCredentialsArn:
            Fn::ImportValue: 
                !Sub ${Env}-${AWS::Region}-global-iamprocesscommandsfromapigateway-arn
        AuthorizerUri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Lambda.Arn}/invocations
        IdentitySource: 
            - route.request.querystring.token
```

When I create an authorizer manually using the console, I get this prompt at the end:

[image]

This manually created authorizer works once I hook it up with the $connect endpoint.

So, it is this permission I'm trying to set in my CloudFormation script. I have tried the following settings but it does not work. I keep getting a 500 error:

```
   LambdaPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        DependsOn: 
            - Lambda
            - WebsocketAuthorizer
        Properties:
            Action: lambda:*
            FunctionName: !GetAtt Lambda.Arn
            Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
            SourceArn: !Sub 
                - arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiId}/${Env}/$connect
                - apiId: 
                    Fn::ImportValue:
                        !Sub ${Env}-${AWS::Region}-altosignal-global-websockets
```

Does anybody know the proper lambda permission settings for a custom authorizer for a websocket API Gateway $connect endpoint?

Comment: can you add the definition for `AuthorizerCredentialsArn`? Is it the same as `LambdaPermission`?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a Lambda Permission. This is what I have for setting the permission and it works well. The only difference I can see here is that the SourceArn is not given. This will hopefully give you a place to start.

```
Permission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    DependsOn:
    - "WebsocketApi"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt Lambda.Arn
      Principal:
        Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - "apigateway."
          - Ref: "AWS::URLSuffix"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using samcli and have this as authorizer permission and this works for me.

```
  AuthorizerFunctionPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    DependsOn:
      - WebSocketApi
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: arn:aws:lambda:AWS_REGION:YOUR_ACCOUT_ID:function:AUTHORIZER_FUNCTION_NAME
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

Just substitute AWS_REGION, YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID, and AUTHORIZER_FUNCTION_NAME